# How to Evaluate JavaScript code from .NetCore

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.1

I need to evaluate Javascript code from .netcore 2.1 project

```
    string vRule = "var input = arguments[0]; if (!input) return \"\"; if(input.length != 7) return \"a fixed string length of 7 is required\"; else return \"\"";
    string spResponse = "sdfsd23";

    string errorText =
        _jscriptEval.EvalToString(new List<object>
            {
                "var args = new Array('" + spResponse +
                "');\r\n validateRule(args);\r\n function validateRule(arguments){" + vRule +
                "}\r\n"
            });
```

Comment: Hi,  @Pratik Bhoir, please provide the logic of your java script codes. From your codes, it's hard to understand and  then we could try to transform for u.

Comment: The Jint Packaged worked properly as expected.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [Jint](https://github.com/sebastienros/jint). Jint implements the ECMA 5.1 spec and can be use from any .NET implementation (Xamarin, .NET Framework, .NET Core). Just use the NuGet package and has no dependencies to other stuff - it’s a single .dll and you are done!
Just transform your javascript code into a function and run it like this (this is just an example, not your implementation):

```
  var engine = new Engine()
    .Execute("function MyFunction(a, b) { return a + b; }")
    ;

engine.Invoke("MyFunction", 1, 2); // -> 3
```

You have more explanations and examples on https://github.com/sebastienros/jint

Comment: Thanks, @d-a , I was searching for some similar package was not able to find.